# How do I pass arguments / parameters to model

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla

Following the tutorial how to create a joomla 2.5 component I'm stucked to pass arguments from view.html.php to my model.

```
$items = $this->get('TableData');
```

and my TableData model would expect to get the following arguments

```
 public function getTableData($table, $index_column, $columns) {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not do this using the view's get method. Instead you would have to grab the model into the view and call the function directly in the view:

```
$model = $this->getModel();
$items = $model->getTableData($table, $index_column, $columns);
```

Alternately, you could create different entry points in the model that would be able to figure these input options either from state information or preset. Many would argue that this would lead to a better application design, since using my code above is putting what should be model logic in the view.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. So I should call the model in the view.html.php or is a good approach as well if I do this already in my Controller

Comment: `$this->get('TableData');` should be in your view already. This gets the data for the view to display, I would assume. If that is the case, then you should call the model from the view. General rule is the view calls the model to get information to display. The controller should call the model to save/update items.

Comment: Done. Why do all the Joomla docs show that if it is a bad idea? (I have definitely been blindly doing this without thinking about it for a while...)

Comment: It's basically a legacy from PHP4. There is no harm in it but it's not needed with PHP5. Yes Marko, the docs are sometimes outdated. It need volunteers to improve them, nobody get's paid to write docs.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addon to David's answer.

Because most of the data usually comes from POST / GET methods, depending on your application,  you may want to look at how loadFormData() from `loadFormData` `JModelForm` or `populateState` gets overridden in specific Joomla components.

Basically the state of model is set directly from POST data, using JInput.

Also, although it's not a rule or something, 3 parameters is a maximum I would pass to a method. For flexibility I would rather pass an array with can be later extended without changing the method signature.